# Rails: How to make strong parameters easy to read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My app has strong parameters as followings.

How can I make this code easy to read?

This line has a lot of `attributes`

**my controller**

```
  def create
    @schedule = current_user.schedules.build(schedule_params)
    ...
  end

  ...

  def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(:title, :departure_date, rooms_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :room, :room_address, :day, :ccy, :amount, events_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :start_at, :end_at, :title, :detail, :category, :ccy, :amount, amounts_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :ccy, :amount]]])
  end
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: Excellent question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart of strings, ruby mostly ignores white space. This makes it possible to easily break a line of code into multiple parts. You can make use of that to make your parameters easier to read:

```
def schedule_params
  params.require(:schedule).permit(
    :title, :departure_date,
    rooms_attributes: [
      :id, :_destroy, :room, :room_address, :day, :ccy, :amount,
      events_attributes: [
        :id, :_destroy, :start_at, :end_at, 
        :title, :detail, :category, :ccy, :amount, 
        amounts_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :ccy, :amount]
      ]
    ])
end
```

Comment: This one feels like the easiest to read for people coming to your code later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Ivan Angelov. I accept your answer because the most `useful` votes so far.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to define the nested arrays seperately e.g.

```
def schedule_params
  amount_attributess = [:id, :_destroy, :ccy, :amount]
  event_attributes = [:id, :_destroy, :start_at, :end_at, :title, :detail, :category, :ccy, :amount, amounts_attributes: amount_attributess]
  room_attributes = [:id, :_destroy, :room, :room_address, :day, :ccy, :amount, events_attributes: event_attributes]
  params.require(:schedule).permit(:title, :departure_date, rooms_attributes: room_attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add some Indentation, it improves legibility and also reduces the chances of occurring bugs on your code, it's definitely a best practice!

You can also follow some coding style guide like this ones:

- [Github Ruby Styleguide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby)
- [Airbnb Ruby Styleguide](https://github.com/airbnb/ruby)
- [Community-driven Styleguide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

```ruby
def schedule_params
  params.require(:schedule).permit(
    :title,
    :departure_date,
    rooms_attributes: [
      :id,
      :_destroy,
      :room,
      :room_address,
      :day,
      :ccy,
      :amount,
      events_attributes: [
        :id,
        :_destroy,
        :start_at,
        :end_at,
        :title,
        :detail,
        :category,
        :ccy,
        :amount,
        amounts_attributes: [
          :id,
          :_destroy,
          :ccy,
          :amount
        ]
      ]
    ]
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def schedule_params
  params.require(:schedule).permit!
end
```

Looks easy to read? Yes.

Secure? No.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

Make a constant in the model with params array. That way you don't have to retype them in the controller

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  PARAMS = [:name, :email, :password]
end
```

Then in controller

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(User::PARAMS)
end
```

You could even combine multiple models together in the controller if they are nested